# ConstraintLayout views in top left corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout, view-hierarchy

Every time I create views like `Button` and `TextView` in `ConstraintLayout`, they all get stuck at the top corner instead of where I placed them.

I tried to create new activities and change the emulator, but the result is still the same.

This is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image]

What may be the issue?

Comment: show your xml code.

Comment: Do you want to show your button and text at the centre ?

Comment: yes this is exactly what im trying to do

Comment: Use Relative Layout Instead. At least thats how I tackled the problem now.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous answers if you do not provide constraints in constraint layout It will sett the element to top left corner. If you are new android, you should start with basic activity and if you want move UI elements in layout editor freely use a relative layout instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As stated in [Constraint Layout guides](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview):

> If a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).
>
> You must add at least one horizontal and one vertical constraint for the view.

I guess you haven't applied any constraints.

Either manually apply constraints to the view, or let the layout editor do it for you using *"Infer constraints"* button:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints... this is only to make editing easier

In other words, the View will "stay where you leave it" until you add constraints.

The reason it looks different in the Preview vs your app is because anything in your XML with `tools:` is [going to be removed from the code when your app runs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html). These options are only for the Android Studio layout editor, not representative of what you should expect to see when the code runs.

And it may be troublesome for beginners because

> a missing constraint won't cause a compilation error

**However**

> the Layout Editor indicates missing constraints as an error in the toolbar. To view the errors and other warnings, click **Show Warnings and Errors** (red button with number). To help you avoid missing constraints, the Layout Editor can automatically add constraints for you with the [Autoconnect and infer constraints features](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#use-autoconnect-and-infer-constraints)

[More details](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: I find that this happens even in the `Layout Editor`. For example, if I drop an `ImageView` into the middle of the layout, it will still get stuck in the upper left corner. I have to change its dimensions before I can move it, or do anything with it. This doesn't seem to be the documented behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what *"stays where you leave it"*  means

Answer (score 3):

A quick, easy way to fix this is to click on the component (TextView, ImageView, etc.) and click the infer constraints button. It looks like 2 yellow plus signs.

infer constraints image

[image: infer constraints image]

Answer (score 2):

add this in xml to the button etc

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57"
```

then play with it in the design.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this type of problem happens when you use **ConstraintLayout** .

- So Go to **Preview** From Android Studio.
- Select That **button** you want to set at the specific position
- At last just click the **infer constrains** button as i mention in
  the picture below on a red circle.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/sDu1ghP.jpg]

Thats All run the project and see magic

Thank you