# Android Studio Emulator do not show the designed layout

Tags: android, layout, emulation

[Android Studio Emulator do not show the designed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMAl7.png)

I am trying to make my first app in Android but even the my simple app with just 2 Text Fields and 1 Button always float to the corner of the Emulator. I have tried to change the Android Image to x86 or Install HAXM, or tried on another computer with different layout designs but things do not change.

I am a newbie in Android so I hope will get help from you.

Here is my file activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.button.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="62dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log In"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="118dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your activity_main.xml?

Comment: We cannot help you without your code so add your code , you even tried that on another computer so mostly its because your code have some issues not the emulator.

Comment: yes I will post it now

Comment: I have posted the activity_main.xml file. Hope you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **not** applied any constraints to your views, which force them to be drawn in the top left corner (0,0). Apply appropriate constraints (left, top, right, bottom).

Reason, why you see everything ok in layout editor, is that you've applied hardcoded values via `tools:` namespace, which will take effect only for layout editor, but not on runtime.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner/42594154#42594154) answer which exactly depicts your case.

Comment: If you know of an existing post that answers the question, please vote as a duplicate, rather than repeating answers across multiple posts.

Comment: Thank you, finally I got solution from you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. check your manifest file, see if your activity already in the manifest.
2. check your activity, see if your activity already extend Activity or AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I am posting the file activity_main.xml above so you can check it.

Comment: For your suggestions, it has already in the Manifest (because it only has one MainActivity), and it also already extend AppCompatActivity. But though it not works :(