# (Android Studio) App looks normal on editor, but when I open it on the emulator, it messes up. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

This is the error I'm having:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w13XL.png 
(Can't embed images yet, need 10 reputation)

Any help is greatly aprecciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner

Comment: Thanks, resolved =)