# Image view doesn't appear on Activity (it's OK on AppCompatActivity)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have simple application which has one ImageView and text box

At First I started with AppCompactActivity, it works.

However when I changed AppCompatActivity to Activity.
(I would like to delete the title bar)

ImageView is disappeared(Droid).

I think I have constraint of ImageView.

How can I show the ImageView??

[image]

```
package jp.virararara.antbuid.bb;

//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.Activity

//class TopActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
class TopActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top)
    }
}
```

activity_top.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="208dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="153dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Are you purposely using Java code?

Comment: Are you purposely using Java code?

Comment: apply wight for your xml design layouts.

Comment: @Daniele bit confused and made mistake.

Comment: None of your views have constraints

Comment: Does this happen? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to delete the title bar

Then you change the theme of the Activity, it's not necessary to extend a separate class.

You don't need a FrameLayout to display an image

But the real issue is

1) `app:srcCompat` is meant to be loaded by an `AppCompat` class

[Android: What is the difference between app:srcCompat=" " and android:src=" "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)

2)  you are using a ConstraintLayout with no constraints, and you can refer to the symptoms of that here.

[ConstraintLayout views in top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner)

Comment: Thanks for your constraintlayout idea. I have added constraint layout to the imageview.

Comment: Thanks!! If I changed  app:srcCompat=" " to android:src=" "? it works. however If I drop new images, xml automatically use app:srcCompat.

Comment: `app:srcCompat is meant to be loaded by an AppCompat class` : what does this mean exactly? Where is this documented? `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` are not really loading the vector drawables, are they?

Comment: @Sébastien The `LayoutInflater` will load the drawable resources, yes.