# Widgets are overlapping in the activity in Android app

Tags: java, android

I am a self learner of android and I am trying to make an app that displays message as Toast.I made the app on Android Studio and it seems okay but when I run it on my phone which runs on Android 5.0 ,all the widgets are overlapped while in studio all of it looks fine.Please Help.
This is how it looks on phone:

[image: This is how it looks on Andro]

This is how it looks on Android

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rahulranjan.toast1.MainToast">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/test1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btnClick"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:textColor="#00C957"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Below to see Toast :"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
    android:textColor="#E3CF57"
    />
```

And yeah I have used ConstrainLayout,I don't know why its not displaying here on this site.
Thanks

Comment: remove constraint and put relative layout in the root

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRoy ,changing it to relative layout worked but can you tell me what was the problem with constraint layout?

Comment: Refer to the linked questions in the banner at the top of the page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43422980) explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You're using a constraint layout. You're not giving these constraints. Add constraints to these or else they default pop to the top left:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click Below to see Toast :"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
android:textColor="#E3CF57"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/test1"
/>
```

Comment: I have used:<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Comment: Yeah sorry, I only just saw that. I've edited my comment to explain better. Hope that helps!