# Android .xml File Doesn't Match Emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator, emulation

I have created an extremely simple example of my problem. In this app there are two buttons (neither of them do anything just supposed to be there and be able to be clicked). In the .xml file I have the Pixel phone selected and have laid out the buttons to fit the screen correctly (using match_parent for width) ([.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC4ua.png)). But when I run the application on my Pixel emulator (not edited at all) only second button shows up and the width isn't right ([Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53mU3.png)). This feels like it has to be operator error considering the extreme differences. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner

Comment: Perfect thank you so much!