# Elements overlapping on each other in my android studio emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to `Android Studio`, when I created my app all my elements overlapped on each other. I am not sure how to edit this code. Please give me a detailed description.

**Layout editor and emulator result**

[image]

**Code for the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="com.example.first.anew.MainActivity"> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Login"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="343dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="177dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:text="username"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="117dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="218dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try changing `tools:` to `app:` if doesn't work use infer constraint option

Answer (score 3):

Your emulator screen and the layout editor are different because of `tools` namespace. In a few words, it is a tool that helps you to better visualise the written code. This tool also generates constraints like `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="343dp"`, which inform the layout editor on how it should draw the views. The problem is that this constraints will not be present in your app code, resulting in that weird behaviour when all views are overlapped (since the above mentioned constraints are not used in the app code we can deduct that there are no constraint at all).

Since you are a beginner I would recommend to start with a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` because I think that `ConstraintLayout` is harder to understand, use and debug.

Answer (score 0):

put the whole code. if you are using Relativelayout, this will happen. change it to Linearlayout at the top i mean the bottom most element, and put orientation as vertical

Comment: and if this doesn't answer your que, share the whole code and the design what you want to achieve.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.first.anew.MainActivity">    
_**in between these the above mentioned codes are there**_


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner/49760488#49760488) - for me my soltion works...

> add this in xml to the button etc
>
> ```
> app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57"
> ```
>
> then play with it in the design.
>
> Good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

you can click the infer Constraints button[click on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3obR.jpg)

and run your programme again..it will solve your problem