# Android studio constraint layout button wrong position

Tags: android, layout

I'm quite new to android studio and java programming,

I have a constraint layout in my app with ImageView and Buttons,

All of them have:

`tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1181dp"`

I know this is only shown in the editor, how can i put my stuff in right position when compile ?

I have tried LinearLayout and relative but I have a ScrollView too , I didn't manage to implement it correctly with linear or relative, maybe I should not use layout like this way...

Here is my layout file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight = "1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/r1"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/scroll1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="9dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:text="Les Poissons Blancs"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Ablette"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="275dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Barbeau"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="426dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Brème"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="577dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Carpe"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="728dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Carassin"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="879dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Chevesne"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1030dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Gardon"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1181dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ablette"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="213dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="270dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/barbeau"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="371dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="426dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/breme"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="371dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="577dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/carpe"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="371dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="728dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="129dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/carassin"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="380dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="879dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevesne"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="380dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1030dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gardon"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="380dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1181dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>´
```

When click ctrl+F1 on an ImageView it's said that I must add constraints by dragging from the edge connections , I tried to do it in the editor, but it failed

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can find here why your button is not displayed properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165683/3734172

Comment: Show your output.

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2017-39-4-1506592743-out.png

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with constraintLayout to display item wherever we want especially with androidStudio editor

[image: Just link item between them]

And in your code you don't have any constraintProperties 
For exemple for you button5 to be below button4 :

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it 's much better with buttons , they are now in the right place,

for all buttons i add `android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                           android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonxxx"`

i have tried the same for all the imageview with

```
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="440dp"
```

it works for the imageview1 and 2 but , the others remain on the left size of the window (?!)

or the square is on the right place but the image hasn't follow ....

Answer (score 0):

that's ok applying margins , thanks a lot

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:text="Barbeau"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="barbeau1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />
```