# Android Studio Preview Not The Same

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio, so I need a little help. I am working on 2.3.3. So the preview doesn't match the view that I get on the actual emulator. Please help.

Preview Image

[image]

Emulator Image

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#006699"
    tools:context="a.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My App"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="85px"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="100dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="264dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove tools : attribute from xml as the only works in preview

```html
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My App"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="85px"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

[This is good article for constraint layout](https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013)