# Constraint Layout Preview does not equal to builded application

Tags: android, layout, constraints

Preview Screen Image:

[image: Preview Screen Image]

App Screen Image:

[image: App Screen Image]

I use a fragment that has a ConstraintLayout and views wrapped with NestedScrollView

It's preview screen has no error but when build this app and install, this fragment does not appear same preview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConstraintLayout views in top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner)

Comment: may be you give wrong constraint.add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because the preview is a different screen resolution, switch the panel to the corresponding resolution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W78r2.png)

Comment: i use Pixel phone Resolution and my test mobile phone is also Pixel phone