# Getting error as This view is not constrained, it only has design time positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

Tags: android

[image]when I am creating a new Design am getting an error as "This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints".**I know there already have  an answer for this query but in all those answer its been said to click on "constraint layout"but I am not getting that constraint layout in my design as shown (in first image)**
[image]

Comment: "I am not getting that constraint layout in my design" -- sure you are. Look at your Component Tree pane, in the lower left of your screenshot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner for more.

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer!!!

If you're not getting "constraint layout"even after Right click,click on image as shown below [image]