# Android Studio preview and Emulator show a big diffrence

Tags: android, layout, emulation

I'm new in the android programming.

I made a new view in the android studio but the emulator doesn't show it like the preview. I don't have any idea what the reason is.

[image: Preview in Android Studio]

[image: Emulator]

The ConstraintLayout was default. Is it possible to use another one? Why are all my elements at the top of the view? Is a attribute missing?

XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.DetailDeviceInformation">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.11"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="147dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weight_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:text="@string/gewicht"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/weightDropdown"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.00" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="204dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.26"
        android:text="@string/wiederholungen"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/repetitionDropdown"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:text="@string/button"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="418dp"
    tools:text="Speichern" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: is this your full xml code ?

Comment: I insert the missing code snippet above.

Comment: You are missing constraints on your constraint layout, remove tools:ignore="MissingConstraints". The preview is displaying that layout (the well-formed one) due to layout_editor_absoluteX and layout_editor_absoluteY attributes. This attributes works only during preview but if you don't add constraint you'll occurr into problems at runtime. If you remove tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" the editor will notify you about this issue

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I removed  tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" but it looks identically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConstraintLayout views in top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner)

Comment: @Larissa all that removing `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` will do is allow Android Studio to tell you that your views are missing constraints. You still need to add constraints! See the question I linked above for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weight_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:text="sss"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/weightDropdown"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.26"
            android:text="ssss"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/repetitionDropdown"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.07" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:text="Speichern" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you use Constraint layout as the base layout. But the declaration is missing.

so add below code in the top

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I find you are using textView and spinner and wrap this two in a linear layout. but you don't need to use linear layout. you should remove those two excess linear layouts.

Answer (score 0):

try using this way `realtive layout`:

change :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.DetailDeviceInformation">



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

to :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.DetailDeviceInformation"
>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code as below, to populate spinners follow the documentation at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/weightDropdown"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/repetitionDropdown" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/repetitionDropdown"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weightDropdown"
        tools:text="Speichern" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```