# Is my code correct for launching two android apps using android intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

*this is my code*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void Smart1(View view){
        Intent Smart1app =getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("project.developers.com.demoproject");
        startActivity(Smart1app);



        }


    public void Smart2(View view) {
        Intent Smart2app =getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.smart.hayat");
        startActivity(Smart2app);

    }}
```

when i run application using this code, i cant access both apps.What is the the logical error or my logic itself might be wrong

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "i cant access both apps".

Comment: When i debug the app both icons of the app appears to be merged  on top of right side that makes it difficult to launch the applications.Im not able to launch individual applications

Comment: Are you talking about the buttons? If so, that's a problem with your layout XML.

Comment: Exactly, Im talking about buttons both buttons appear to be merged on top of right side even when i click on them only single application launches everytime.

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:onClick="Smart1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_l

Comment: tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:onClick="Smart2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="241dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code, XML, or logs. Please don't post it in comments.

Comment: [The linked duplicate now at the top of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner) explains why your `<ImageView>`s overlap at runtime.

Comment: see my updated anwser

Answer (score -1):

ContrainLayout is bit difficult to understand.
In this xml I have used LinearLayout. Inside that I have added two ImagesView On each ImagesView there is onClick property is added.
Please go through the code, If you didn't understand let me know.

Here is your xml file

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="Smart1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="Smart1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And Here your java file

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void Smart1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("project.developers.com.demoproject"));
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void Smart2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.smart.hayat"));
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error in xml code called unexpected end

Comment: Yeah, even though I'm getting error message "failed linking references

Comment: On which line you getting these errors.