# How to fix messed up layout on Android studio

Tags: javascript, android

I'm not a real programmer, I'm learning tho, I know nothing about javascript but once again I'm now studying it from the beginning. I'm studying by that ''development course of android, how to create 15 apps'' so I did download the eclipse and the one recommended by the course ''Android Studio''. I did what it says on the tutorial but by the time I try to run it it's like a mess

This is the image of the messed up running:
[image]

Comment: Please add your XML code.

Comment: Are you sure you are learning JavaScript and not Java?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using ConstraintLayout. In ConstraintLayout you need to apply constraints to views (like Button) in order to make them stay where you want them to (to put it simply).

[Constraint Layout guides](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview):

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints.
>
> However, this is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

You problem might have been solved in [ConstraintLayout views in top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594033/constraintlayout-views-in-top-left-corner).